# Can we scale number of scenarios in Scenario Outline in Specflow?

Tags: specflow

I am writing BDD in Specflow and I want to execute a single scenario N number of times.
But this N number is calculated at runtime. Is there any way so that can execute the same scenario for N number of times?

Comment: Why do you need to repeat the scenario? Does the scenario fail intermittently?

Comment: Actually i want to run this scenario for N different EXamples. But number of examples should be Dynamic

Comment: So you are looking for a more data driven testing approach.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way.
I don't know any unit test runner, where you can at runtime say, please repeat the test n-times.

Comment: Thanks for reply and would like to thanu for your all help. I read many forums and your responses which clear my doubts. Could you pls answer 1 more questions?   Is ExternalData plugin is free or not?

Comment: All our stuff is free. The ExternalData Plugin is open source at  https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow/tree/master/Plugins/SpecFlow.ExternalData